# How to set default Home screen on Nougat/7.1.1?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, 7.1-nougat, home-screen, lenovo, home-button

It's driving me crazy.

On a Moto G5s Plus (with Android 7.1.1) how do I set the screen I want as the default one, so that is shown when I press the Home button?

At the moment the left-most screen (of 3 screens) is the default. I wan to set the middle one as default one.

- I already disabled *Google Feed*.
- I already tried to long press one screen, get the setup view (change order, remove, Widgets, etc) **but there is no icon** (usually a "Home") at the top of the screen to be pressed for setting the default screen. I find this method everywhere but **doesn't behave like that**
- I already tried to pinch-in with 3 fingers; nothing happens

Comment: Did you [try this](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-206680/). I vaguely recall doing something similar on this device (currently not with me to test)

Comment: I know that method but doesn't fit my need. And I read that **"The left panel is the default Home panel"**. No way to change behaviour? Why such opinionated limit?

Answer (score 0):

Long press on screen, then hold and drag wanted screen to left (first) position